# How to programatically put same sprite mutiple times in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I am trying to generate multiple sprites in my scene using just a single sprite. I found it difficult, when I tried using array of sprite and the sprite renderer, because in my scene I only see a single sprite. I also want to display the sprites in different areas in my Unity Scene.

The Main Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SampleCode : MonoBehaviour {

    float posX = -4.5F;
    float posY = -0.65F;

    public IEnumerator Start(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            posX = posX + 0.65F;

            if(posX > 3.5F){
                for(float x = 0.50F; x < 2.5F; x = x + 0.50F){
                    posY = -1.5F + x;
                    posX = -4.15F + x;;
                }
            }

        string path = "file:///C:/Users/Pankaj Sharma/Documents/untitled.bmp";
            SpriteRenderer rend = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            Sprite sprite = new Sprite();
            WWW www = new WWW(path);
            yield return www;
            sprite = Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0, 50, 50),new Vector2(posX, posY),100.0f);
            rend.sprite = sprite;
        }
    }   
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one `SpriteRenderer` that's why you only see one sprite.

If you have multiple objects in your scene with a `SpriteRenderer` component you can set your `sprite` to the `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite` for the objects you want in your scene.

Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

You actually in the code, forget to, change their positions. so they are on top of each other.

you change positions in start method,
and in the end, x and y positions are just the end calculation
5 times for that for loop * 0.65 ..

and put all there

try putting the create method inside the for loop where you have calculations for posx posy.